# Python one-liner to convert float to string

Tags: python

I want to convert a float between 0.0 and 39.9 into a string. Replace the tens digit with an L, T or Y if it's a 1, 2 or 3 respectively. And append an M if it's in the ones. For example, 22.3 would return T2.3 and 8.1 would return M8.1 and so forth. Otherwise, return the float.

This code works of course, but I wondering if there was a simpler (if not one-liner) solution. Here's the code:

```
def specType(SpT):
  if 0 <= SpT <= 9.9:
    return 'M{}'.format(SpT)
  elif 10.0 <= SpT <= 19.9:
    return 'L{}'.format(SpT - 10)
  elif 20.0 <= SpT <= 29.9:
    return 'T{}'.format(SpT - 20)
  elif 30.0 <= SpT <= 39.9:
    return 'Y{}'.format(SpT - 30) 
  else:
    return SpT
```

Thanks!

Comment: You've got to be careful with all those `float` comparisons (`SpT <= 9.9` etc)

Comment: +1, NPE. What is the desired output when `SpT` is 9.95? Because it's greater than `9.9` and less than `10.0`, it falls through the cracks and reaches the `return SpT` line.

Comment: That's a good point. It's best if I account for that but in truth, it will never come up in the application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about:

```py
def specType(SpT):
    return '{}{}'.format('MLTY'[int(SpT//10)], SpT % 10) if 0.0 <= SpT <= 39.9 else SpT
```

which gives

```
>>> specType(0.0)
'M0.0'
>>> specType(8.1)
'M8.1'
>>> specType(14.5)
'L4.5'
>>> specType(22.3)
'T2.3'
>>> specType(34.7)
'Y4.7'
```

[As noted in the comments, you'll want to think about what to do with numbers which can sneak through your boundaries -- I made one guess; modify as appropriate.]

Comment: :O Mind = Blown! I never knew you could do `//`!

Comment: @yentup You can also use [`divmod`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod) :)

Comment: @yentup That't a good read :) Another two from my bookmark bar: [built-in types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html) and [data model](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) (the latter may be a little more advanced).

Comment: Fantastic! That's exactly it. Thanks!